# Optional Regex group fails for 0 occurrences?

Tags: regex

Here is my Regex statement:

```
^I (?:click|choose) (?:the)? option (.+) from the (.+) (?:select|dropdown)$
```

Here is what tests positive:

> > I click the option thing from the otherThing dropdown

Here is what tests negative:

> > I click option thing from the otherThing dropdown

I was under the impression that `'?'` means
`the preceding character occurs 0 or 1 times only`

So why does it succeed with 1 time but fail with 0 times?

Comment: (Thanks for the formatting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the `the` is optional, but the spaces surrounding it are not. Your regex expects that if the `the` does not appear, there should be two spaces between the `click`/`choose` and the `option`.

Try changing your pattern to this:

```
^I (?:click|choose) (?:the )?option (.+) from the (.+) (?:select|dropdown)$
```

Comment: It's always the simple things. Thank you, this worked!

Edit: (I'll hit accept answer as soon as it lets me)